# How to force users to log in before viewing my site

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like for guests to be redirected to a login page whenever they access the site. There won't be a register form, and the site will only be protected by one username/password.

This is my login.php so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<div id="lg_outr" class="mn_outr">
    <div id="lg_ctnr" class="mn_ctnr">
        <div id="lg_innr" class="mn_innr">

        <form class="lg_frm">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
                <input class="usr_fld" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
                <input class="pw_fld" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input class="sub_btn" type="submit" value="Log in"/>
        </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need help with:

- Checking if a user is logged in through a header.php file
- Forcing guests to the login.php page if not logged in
- Making the login form actually work

Currently coding the site in localhost. Assuming I won't need a database as there's only one username/password.

Really appreciate any help

---

**Found a solution!**

Login.php:

```
<?php  session_start(); ?>      

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['use']))   

 {
    header("Location:index.php"); 
 }

if(isset($_POST['login']))   
{
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $pass = $_POST['pass'];

      if($user == "username1" && $pass == "password1")    
         {                                   
          $_SESSION['use']=$user;


         echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("index.php","_self");</script>';    

        }

        else
        {
            echo "invalid UserName or Password";        
        }
}
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<div id="lg_outr" class="mn_outr">
    <div id="lg_ctnr" class="mn_ctnr">
        <div id="lg_innr" class="mn_innr">

        <form class="lg_frm" action="" method="post">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
                <input class="usr_fld" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username"/>
                <input class="pw_fld" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input class="sub_btn" type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN"/>
        </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then this code at the top of my header.php

```
<?php   session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['use'])) // If session is not set then redirect to Login Page
       {
           header("Location:Login.php");  
       }

 ?>
```

Comment: a simple php code to check if session exists and if not redirect them to log in would suffice i guess?

Comment: if you are running apache then let apace do it with basic ( or digest ) authentication would probably be easiest

Comment: woah! i think you need tutorials in php and mysql. and you do need a database. You said you want to check if the user is logged in. I assume its more than one user

Comment: @FarhanQasim - alright thanks, I'll take a look into that

Comment: @Akintunde007 - Basically, the website I'm developing is a portfolio that can't be public due to the clients. However, it does need to be accessible by certain users that will have the only username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP - 
Use **Cakephp**. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=747K6W40ur0

Using python - 
Use **flask**. https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: recommending frameworks and libraries isn't helpful.. How will the OP learn how authentication and other principles work?

Answer (score 0):

in any protected page, or contained in a `require('config.php')` file:

```
session_start();
$username = 'onlyone';
$password = 'secret';

if(empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['username']) && !empty($_REQUEST['password']) && $_REQUEST['username'] === $username && $_REQUEST['password'] === $password) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    } else {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit;
    }else {
        // we're good
    }
}
```

That should get you started  and allow you to visualize the concept; but listen to some of the comments below your post as well!